# Xamarin Android: How to draw on top of Canvas

Tags: android, xamarin, canvas

I am writing a custom renderer for `Xamarin.Forms`. I am overriding the class `ImageRenderer` to do some tweaks to the image.

However, I want to overlay some parts of the image with circles, so I override the method `void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)`.

Then I modify the `Canvas` a bit by drawing some circles:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    var paint = new Paint
    {
        Color = Color.Red
    };
    paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);

    foreach (var mapObject in _control.PointSource)
    {
        canvas.DrawCircle(mapObject.Location.X, mapObject.Location.Y, 100 / _scaleFactor, paint);
    }

    base.OnDraw(canvas);
}
```

However, everything is drawn on the background. The actual image is always on top. How can one draw circles on top of the image?

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Views.View.OnDraw/

In the docs they say the following:

> the canvas on which the background will be drawn

So the current behaviour was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by moving the circle logic to the function: `void Draw(Canvas canvas)`.